# Pretty-Print JSON Data to a File using Python

Tags: python, json, twitter, pretty-print

A project for class involves parsing Twitter JSON data. I'm getting the data and setting it to the file without much trouble, but it's all in one line. This is fine for the data manipulation I'm trying to do, but the file is ridiculously hard to read and I can't examine it very well, making the code writing for the data manipulation part very difficult.

Does anyone know how to do that from within Python (i.e. not using the command line tool, which I can't get to work)? Here's my code so far:

```
header, output = client.request(twitterRequest, method="GET", body=None,
                            headers=None, force_auth_header=True)

# now write output to a file
twitterDataFile = open("twitterData.json", "wb")
# magic happens here to make it pretty-printed
twitterDataFile.write(output)
twitterDataFile.close()
```

**Note** I appreciate people pointing me to simplejson documentation and such, but as I have stated, I have already looked at that and continue to need assistance. A truly helpful reply will be more detailed and explanatory than the examples found there. *Thanks*

**Also:**
Trying this in the windows command line:

```
more twitterData.json | python -mjson.tool > twitterData-pretty.json
```

results in this:

```
Invalid control character at: line 1 column 65535 (char 65535)
```

I'd give you the data I'm using, but it's very large and you've already seen the code I used to make the file.

Comment: I doubt you actually want to write binary data ("wb")

Comment: I was taught this was necessary for Windows machines and thus far has worked for all of my assignments. If you can offer documentation as to why this might be incorrect, I'd be happy to look at it.

Comment: It's only necessary if you're working with binary files, or other cases where the specific form of line ending (e.g. `\r\n` vs `\n`) is important. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257869/difference-between-binary-and-text-i-o-in-python-on-windows. In your case, you want windows friendly line endings, but you might not get that from the twitter endpoint, so you should open in text mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prettyprint a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You should use the optional argument `indent`.

```
header, output = client.request(twitterRequest, method="GET", body=None,
                            headers=None, force_auth_header=True)

# now write output to a file
with open("twitterData.json", "w") as twitterDataFile:
    # magic happens here to make it pretty-printed
    twitterDataFile.write(
        simplejson.dumps(simplejson.loads(output), indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    )
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked **perfectly**. Can you explain why "sort_keys" needs to be in there?

Comment: It doesn't need to be there but it makes things very pretty and alphabetically sorted.  I tend to use it when I want human readable output.

Comment: Well explained thank you -however not trying to be a &$&# but open/close to write a file isn't encourage, the with structure is generally preferable:
`with open("name_of_file.json", "w") as f:
   f.write(my_formatted_json_var)`

Advantage being you're sure the file will close, say on bigger snippets...

Comment: `with` syntax is definitely nicer, but I try to scale my answers to my audience

Answer (score 134):

You can parse the JSON, then output it again with indents like this:

```
import json
mydata = json.loads(output)
print json.dumps(mydata, indent=4)
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/json.html for more info.

Comment: @Zelbinian: yes it works for simplejson as well.Take a look here http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-1.9.1/docs/index.html

Comment: This results in an empty file.
`header, output = client.request(twitterRequest, method="GET", body=None,
                                headers=None, force_auth_header=True)

twitterDataFile = open("twitterData.json", "wb")
json.dumps(json.loads(output), twitterDataFile, indent=4)
twitterDataFile.close()`

Comment: @Zelbinian - `json.dumps` returns a string. `json.dump` writes to a file.

Answer (score 118):

```
import json

with open("twitterdata.json", "w") as twitter_data_file:
    json.dump(output, twitter_data_file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

You don't need `json.dumps()` if you don't want to parse the string later, just simply use `json.dump()`. It's faster too.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module of python to pretty print.

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

So, in your case

```
>>> print json.dumps(json_output, indent=4)
```

Comment: Tried that route and that unfortunately doesn't work as well as you'd think.

Comment: @Zelbinian: Exactky what do you mean by `doesn't work as well`.?

Comment: It outputted the data in a single line in what looked to be Python dict syntax instead of pretty-printed Json syntax

Comment: Include the output in you question as an edit.So,we can see it.

Comment: using this, arrays are listed out as many lines of each value, it'd be nice to keep the array on one line.

Answer (score 9):

If you are generating new *.json or modifying existing josn file the use "indent" parameter for pretty view json format.

```
import json
responseData = json.loads(output)
with open('twitterData.json','w') as twitterDataFile:    
    json.dump(responseData, twitterDataFile, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you already have existing JSON files which you want to pretty format you could use this:

```
    with open('twitterdata.json', 'r+') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        f.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
        f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import json
def writeToFile(logData, fileName, openOption="w"):
  file = open(fileName, openOption)
  file.write(json.dumps(json.loads(logData), indent=4)) 
  file.close()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

You could redirect a file to python and open using the tool and to read it use more.

The sample code will be,

```
cat filename.json | python -m json.tool | more
```