# pprint(): how to use double quotes to display strings?

Tags: python, pretty-print, pprint

If I print a dictionary using [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html), it always wraps strings around single quotes (`'`):

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint({'AAA': 1, 'BBB': 2, 'CCC': 3})
{'AAA': 1, 'BBB': 2, 'CCC': 3}
```

Is there any way to tell `pprint` to use double quotes (`"`) instead? I would like to have the following behaviour:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint({'AAA': 1, 'BBB': 2, 'CCC': 3})
{"AAA": 1, "BBB": 2, "CCC": 3}
```

Comment: Why do you *need* double quotes? `pprint()` just uses the `repr()` result of the strings, which will use `'` unless a literal `'` quote is contained.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `json.dumps()` instead? JSON uses double quotes for strings...

Comment: Thanks @Martijn, `json.dumps()` does what I need. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to produce JSON; if so, use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({'AAA': 1, 'BBB': 2, 'CCC': 3})
{"AAA": 1, "BBB": 2, "CCC": 3}
```

The `pprint()` function produces *Python representations*, not JSON and quoting styles are not configurable. Don’t confuse the two syntaxes. JSON may at first glance look a lot like Python but there are more differences than just quoting styles:

- JSON is limited to a few specific types only (`{...}` objects with key-value pairs, `[...]` arrays, `"..."` strings, numbers, booleans and nulls). Python data structures are far richer.
- Python dictionary keys can be any hashable object, JSON object keys can only ever be strings.
- JSON booleans are written in lowercase,`true` and `false`. Python uses title-case, `True` and `False`.
- JSON uses `null` to signal the absence of a value, Python uses `None`.
- JSON strings use UTF-16 codepoints, any non-BMP codepoint is [encoded using surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+010000_to_U+10FFFF). Apart from a handful of single-letter backslash escapes such as `\n` and `\"` arbitrary codepoint escapes use `\uXXXX` 16-bit hexadecimal notation. Python 3 strings cover all of Unicode, and the syntax supports `\xXX`, `\uXXXX`, and `\UXXXXXXXX` 8, 16 and 32-bit escape sequences.

If you want to produce indented JSON output (a bit like `pprint()` outputs indented Python syntax for lists and dictionaries), then add  `indent=4` and `sort_keys=True` to the `json.dumps()` call:

```
>>> print json.dumps({'AAA': 1, 'CCC': 2, 'BBB': 3}, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
{
    "AAA": 1,
    "BBB": 2,
    "CCC": 3
}
```

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-python-prettyprint-a-json-file

Comment: This fixes the single->double quotes, but this is insufficient for manual viewing because it doesn't prettyprint the output.

Comment: @travelingbones the point was that the OP was trying to produce JSON, and was using the wrong tool. They were not actually trying to pretty print!  That said, the `json.dumps()` function can be configured to pretty print, up to a point.

Comment: I understand. I'm facing the same issue, but I need both-- I need to read the output json manually, and plug it into something that takes .json format. I just wanted to include the information I found-- that this does indeed switch the single to double quotes, but doesn't pretty print it.

Comment: For pretty printed JSON see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-python-prettyprint-a-json-file. Again, that was never the point of this answer.

Comment: Check. it was clear from my initial comment that you answered the original question. To wrap this up, I think this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-python-prettyprint-a-json-file uses your solution with an indent parameter that helps with viewing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Are you aware of any performance implications of using 
- `pprint.pformat()` Vs
- `json.dumps()`
while printing a large JSON. `json.dumps()` is expensive?

Comment: @SubhakarKS: `pprint` is pure-python code intended as a developer tool, while the `json` module uses a C extension to improve its performance. `pprint` tools also output **Python** syntax, not JSON, you can't compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the OP wanted JSON, but I do not want JSON and pprint is so close to giving me what I do want: `black`-compatible Python source, which requires that I use `"` instead of `'`.

I settled on `.replace("'", '"')` with `pformat()`, although this is both ugly and fragile ☹️:

```
import pprint

# Note: my code auto-generates my_dict parsing a file (not black-formatted here)
my_dict = ["spam", "eggs", "lumberjack", "knights", "ni", "eggs", "lumberjack", "knights", "ni"]

pprinter = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
formatted_code = (
    pprinter.pformat(my_dict)
    .replace("[ ", "[\n  ")  # break after opening bracket
    .replace("']", "',\n]")  # break before closing bracket, add comma
    .replace("'", '"')  # use double quotes
)
with open("example_module.py", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    outfile.write('"""Module containing auto-generated ALL_MR_HEADERS."""\n')
    outfile.write(f"ALL_MR_HEADERS = {formatted_code}\n")
```

The resulting example_module.py is `black`-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm against using modules for simple things, but over the time `pprint` is becoming useless and not catching up with the Python 3 evolution. At least they could have added this option as a parameter.

So take advantage of the `black` module that prints your objects in pretty format already.

Here is the code,

```
import black
print(black.format_file_contents(str(D), fast=False, mode=black.FileMode()))
```

Will print

```
 '{"AAA": 1, "BBB": 2, "CCC": 3}'
```