# How to prettyprint (human readably print) a Python dict in json format (double quotes)?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pretty-print

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087662/pprint-how-to-use-double-quotes-to-display-strings/16087800?noredirect=1#comment59693473_16087800). I need to both prettyprint a python dict (so I can visually inspect/modify it), and I need to have the output in json format (with the double quotes).

`pprint` module prettyprints the dict but uses single quotes (not json!). That's the topic of the linked other question/answer.

`json.dumps` will use the double quotes, but prints it in a big line (not human readable!)

How can we achieve both?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html):

```
import json

print(json.dumps(
    {'4': 5, '6': 7},
    sort_keys=True,
    indent=4,
    separators=(',', ': ')
))
```

Comment: While it would convert the `None` object to `null` which raise null was not a object exception

Comment: You might want to add `ensure_ascii=False`, otherwise unicode characters will look like `\u0435`.

Comment: @RyanChou you can do `null = None` before importing/copy pasting the result to avoid the exception.

Comment: In python3.4+, no need to specify separators as `(',', ': ')` as that is the default (even if indent is not `None`)