# How to format python dictionary print output like JavaScript?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python but come from JavaScript
and I was trying to print an object/dictionary to terminal by using `print(vars(client))` but came out unformatted like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG96D.png).

I'm used to Node JS terminal outputs and was wondering how I can format the Python output like in JS.

I printed out [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7HlB.png) using a similar Node module in JavaScript (I'm using the vscode terminal)

Comment: How about printing it in JSON format, such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021332/how-to-prettyprint-human-readably-print-a-python-dict-in-json-format-double-q

Comment: The built-in pprint library may help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Comment: [Please don't post images of text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: I removed the javascript and nodejs tags because your question isn't really about those things, it is about how to get python to output dictionaries in a certain format

Comment: See also `devtools.debug` (3rd party)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pprint library which can be used to print dictionary output in a formatted way. Here is an example:

```
import pprint
dictionary = {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
pprint.pprint(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'bar': 2, 'foo': 1}
```

Comment: you might want to add an example of the actual output

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to be actually compatible with other JSON parsers, use the `json` module. It takes care of special cases like `None` correctly becoming `null`, enforcing doubly-quoted strings etc.

```py
import json
d = {"foo": None, "bar": "Hello world!"}
print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
# {
#     "foo": null,
#     "bar": "Hello world!"
# }
```