# List prints with ' or "

Tags: python, list, format

I was wondering, when printing a list of words and one of those words says is.. it's. A list prints out on screen as `['joe', 'bob', "it's"]`.  Notice joe and bob are in `'` while it's is in `"`.

Question: is there a way to make all list items print out with `"` and not `'` so the `print(mylist)` would come out as `["joe", "bob", "it's"]`?

I looked up printing out lists and print function but there was really no documentation on if this could be adjusted. Seems like the format of the list is preset when using the print statement. Just curious.

This is in Python.

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: Sorry, Language is python.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One neat trick is to use `json.dumps`

```py
import json

words = ["joe", "it's","bob", 'te"st']

print(json.dumps(l))

# outputs ["joe", "it's", "bob", "te\"st"]
```

or the hacky way:

```py
words = ["joe", "it's","bob", 'te"st']

format = '["' + '", "'.join(words) + '"]'

print(format)

# outputs ["joe", "it's", "bob", "te"st"]
# note the unescaped double quote
```

or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73925132/4935162) that uses the `black` module.

in any case, this a purely a "printing" thing and it has no effect whatsoever on the '"value"' of the items in the list.