# Convert python dict to json object with formatted keys and values

Tags: python, json

So i have my dict from my form post

```
post_dict = dict(request.POST)
item_data = {}

for key, value in post_dict.items():
   if 'item_data' in key:
      field = key.split('[')[1].replace(']', ' ')
      item_data[key] = ' '.join(value)

data = json.dumps(item_data)
print(data)
```

Right now it prints as follows:

```
{"item_data[username]": "johndoe", "item_data[email]": "johndoe@gmail.com",...
```

i just need it to print like so:

```
{
  "username": "johndoe",
  "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
  ...
}
```

How can I remove "item_data" and format the key and values appropriately?

Comment: `item_data[key] = ...` right after calculating `field` as the wanted key... so close.  Try `item_data[field] = ...` instead!

Comment: as for the indentation / etc. check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-python-prettyprint-a-json-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `item_data[field] = ...` per Tadhg McDonald-Jensen's comment and replace

```
data = json.dumps(item_data)
```

with

```
data = json.dumps(item_data, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))
```