# How to create a json from subproccess in python

Tags: json, python-2.7, file, text, subprocess

I'm not sure if I'm titling my question correctly, but I have the following situation:

I am subprocessing a Scala script which ingests a json file, and the output is a string in json format. Right now I have the following code:

`with open("stdout.txt", "w") as out:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['sbt', '--error', 'run /jsonfolder/Example.json'], cwd = BASEDIR, stdout = out)
    print out`

which writes the `stdout.txt` file in my directory containing the outputted string in json format. However, I'd like to "transform" this .txt file into a .json where it is "pretty" and "structured."

I've tried `with open("stdout.json", "w") as out:` instead, but it did not work.

Comment: to clarify, the output is correct but just not in the format you want? this post might help if you haven't seen it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-python-prettyprint-a-json-file

Comment: Yep! That did the trick! Thanks much.