# Error in parsing the json and formatting to pretty json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-requests

I have used requests module and now i got the data back in json format and by taking help from this [How to Python prettyprint a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944035/5908241) i have written my code and while executing the code it gave me an errro `Expected a string or buffer`, so i have changed the variable passed to the parser to string. Now it again gave another error.

```
#Import
import requests
import json

r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
print(r.status_code)
got_data_in_json = r.json()
parsed_json = json.loads(str(got_data_in_json))
print(json.dumps(parsed_json, indent=4 ,sort_keys=True))
```

Error Log:

```
python requests_post.py
200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests_post.py", line 8, in <module>
    parsed_json = json.loads(str(got_data_in_json))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

The problem is, `str(got_data_in_json)` is *not a valid JSON*:

```
In [2]: str(got_data_in_json)
Out[2]: "{u'files': {}, u'origin': u'50.57.61.145', u'form': {u'key': u'value'}, u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/post', u'args': {}, u'headers': {u'Content-Length': u'9', u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate', u'Accept': u'*/*', u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.11.1', u'Host': u'httpbin.org', u'Content-Type': u'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, u'json': None, u'data': u''}"
```

The `got_data_in_json` is already a Python data structure which you can dump:

```
got_data_in_json = r.json()
print(json.dumps(got_data_in_json, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

`r.json()` parses the JSON for you and returns a Python data structure. There is no need to call `json.loads()` on that data.

Answer (score 1):

`r.json()` returns json

so you don't need to `json.loads(str(got_data_in_json))`

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
print(r.status_code)
got_data_in_json = r.json()
print(json.dumps(got_data_in_json, indent=4 ,sort_keys=True))
```

output :

```
200
{
    "args": {},
    "data": "",
    "files": {},
    "form": {
        "key": "value"
    },
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Length": "9",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Host": "httpbin.org",
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.11.1"
    },
    "json": null,
    "origin": "103.227.98.245",
    "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```