# Python: pprint nested dictionary with a newline for each nesting

Tags: python

I have the following data stucture:

```
{'row_errors': {'hello.com': {'template': [u'This field is required.']}}}
```

When I use [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) in Python, I am getting

```
{'row_errors': {'hello.com': {'template': [u'This field is required.']}}}
```

However, I would very much like it to be printed like:

```
{'row_errors': 
    {'hello.com': 
        {'template': [u'This field is required.']}}}
```

Is this possible to configure via `pprint`?
I prefer `pprint` because I am printing this inside a [Jinja](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/) template.

Comment: I propose you the alternative:  `import json;  print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))`

Comment: `pprint()` isn't all that configurable.

Comment: Try to change the width argument to 40: `pprint(..., width=40)`. The result however is not 100% match like the one you need.

Comment: If you're just looking to visualize the nesting structure (and don't want extra lines for brackets), consider https://pypi.org/project/asciitree/. Nice visual, once you get OrderedDict structure right. (Not affiliated, just a fan).

Answer (score 5):

Like the [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) suggested in the comments, you can use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

Quoting from [Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944035)'s answer:

> The `json` module already implements some basic pretty printing with > the `indent` parameter:

```
>>> import json
>>>
>>> your_json = '["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
>>> parsed = json.loads(your_json)
>>> print json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
[
    "foo", 
    {
        "bar": [
            "baz", 
            null, 
            1.0, 
            2
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This adds a line for each json open / close bracket, so much longer format than OP. (Consider my asciitree comment directly on OP.)