# Read json file as input and output as pprint?

Tags: python, data-processing

I'm working with a large json file that is currently encoded as one long line.

This makes it unintelligable for other people to work with, so I want to render it using pprint.

At the moment I'm trying to import the full file and print as `pprint` but my output looks like this:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='hash_mention.json' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

My question is- what is that showing? How can I get it to output the json data as pprint?

The code I've written looks like this:

```
import pprint

with open('./hash_mention.json', 'r') as input_data_file:

    pprint.pprint(input_data_file)
```

Comment: `pprint.pprint(input_data_file)` --> `pprint.pprint(input_data_file.read())`

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: I'm using MacOs

Comment: you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-python-prettyprint-a-json-file) answer... HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened the file in read mode but forgot to read the file contents.

Just change `pprint.pprint(input_data_file)` with `pprint.pprint(input_data_file.read())` and voila!