# Tree view from json Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a backend that gives me a json response like this

```
{
    "compiler": {
        "type": "GCC",
        "version": "5.4"
    },
    "cpu": {
        "architecture": "x86_64",
        "count": 4
    }
}
```

I need to visualize this response in the form of a tree. What should I do?
Maybe try to transform it to django-model? Or something else?

Comment: You mean you want to print it out like a tree?

Comment: I want to do something like this https://github.com/lmenezes/json-tree

Comment: Why don't you just return it as a REST call and display it using the json-tree library you posted.

Comment: It's hard to explain, but I can only use django :(

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it printed with indentation, the `json` module can already do this using `dumps()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944035/4765406). Alternatively, you can use [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html).

Comment: I need to display this not in the console, but in the browser