# while running pretty command showing error "AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'pretty'"

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

[when I don't use pretty method it is showing output correctly but in single line][Can anyone help me?
thank you in advance]

Comment: You're running this in python not on the mongodb shell, right? Note that the pymongo cursor class (http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html) is different from the MongoDB shell cursor object (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/). It doesn't have a pretty() method. It wouldn't make much sense for it to have it.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to pretty print JSON from python, this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running the script on **PyMongo** so it won't work,**pretty()** uses in **MongoShell** Script