# How to change using python 2.7

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have following python code

```
if b in q:
    print "id:",data['id']
    print "quest:",q
    print "result:",qa['terms'][0]
```

Comment: Where are you trying to create JSON?

Comment: On terminal only. Just need to print on the terminal in json format

Comment: I have a loop going on before if statement. And it's printing results one after the other for 3 things which I need to print

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve]? What are `q` and `b`, and `data`, and `qa`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, start with something like this

You need to form a dictionary, not simply print the values as you get them

```
import json

output = []

# Some code...

if b in q:
    _data = dict()
    _data["id"] = data['id']
    _data["quest"] = q
    _data["result"] = qa['terms'][0]
    output.append(_data)

print json.dumps(output)
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks! It did work but it's not printed in the pretty format I want it to be. It's printing one after the other.

Comment: You can search elsewhere how to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file

Comment: Yeah got it! Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the output in the order keys were read from json file. Meaning result, quest, id but I want it to be in the reverse order as id,quest, result. I've tried OrderedDict to no avail. Is there a way it can be achieved?

Comment: JSON doesn't have ordering. You can print with `sort_keys=True`, but you can not define your own order

Comment: I tried sort_keys but it didn't give me the order I wanted.

Comment: Like I said. JSON has no concept of ordering