# JSON formatter for large file

Tags: python, json

```
import base64
import requests

USERNAME, PASSWORD = 'notworking', 'notworking'

def send_request():
    # Request

    try:
        response = requests.get(
            url="https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nhl/2017-2018-regular/cumulative_player_stats.json", 
            params={
                "fordate": "20171009"
            },
            headers={
                "Authorization": "Basic " +
                     base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(USERNAME,PASSWORD)\
                                      .encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
            }
        )
        print('Response HTTP Status Code: {status_code}'.format(
            status_code=response.status_code))
        print('Response HTTP Response Body: {content}'.format(
            content=response.content))
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        print('HTTP Request failed')
```

That function gave me a json output. I would like to create a file in which the json output will be formatted so that I could analyse the data. A bit like what we could do with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

How could I do such thing? I have seen that question [How to prettyprint a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file), but I am not able to adapt the response to what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck, as this is a very common thing to do in python.

```
import json 

... # Existing code

data = response.json()  # Requests has a built in json response parser 
with open("my_stylish_file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4) 
    # The 'indent' is what makes it multiline and automatically indented
```

Comment: How could I get `response` from my function if I run the function in the python interpreter?

Comment: at the end of `send_request` I would just do a `return response.json()` then you can in the interpreter do `data = send_request()`