# Write json.dumps in readable format to a file in Python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I store JSON data as a string (comming from `json.dumps()`) to files. But complexe data is not readable for humans because linebreaks and indents are missing.

```
>>> import json
>>> d = {'one': 1, 'group': [4,9,7]}
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"one": 1, "group": [4, 9, 7]}'
```

But the string should look more like this.

```
{'one': 1,
 'group': [
           4,
           9,
           7
          ]
}
```

Can I realize this?

Comment: Your second codefragment is not even JSON.

Comment: Please read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps), and provide the `indent` parameter as suggested.

Comment: It is an example not more. Please be more specific how I could fix it to be more json.

Comment: FYI: 1. JSON requires double quotes on keys and string values; and 2. this is still a duplicate, this hasn't changed from 2.x to 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json module in python will honor indenting if you pass an `indent` parameter:

```
import json

d = {'one': 1, 'group': [4,9,7]}
print json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

will output:

```
   {
        "one": 1,
            "group": [ 
            4, 
            9, 
            7
        ]
    }
```

Comment: [This seems familiar.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944035/3001761)