# Best way to print a dict with \n or \t characters in keys or values in python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, repr, pprint

Essentially, I want to print a dictionary such that it uses `str()` instead of `repr()` to stringify its keys and values.

This would be especially useful when saving a traceback string in some json. But this appears to be much more difficult than I would imagine:

```
In [1]: import pprint, json

In [2]: example = {'a\tb': '\nthis\tis\nsome\ttext\n'}

In [3]: print(example)
{'a\tb': '\nthis\tis\nsome\ttext\n'}

In [4]: str(example)
Out[4]: "{'a\\tb': '\\nthis\\tis\\nsome\\ttext\\n'}"

In [5]: pprint.pprint(example)
{'a\tb': '\nthis\tis\nsome\ttext\n'}

In [6]: pprint.pformat(example)
Out[6]: "{'a\\tb': '\\nthis\\tis\\nsome\\ttext\\n'}"

In [7]: json.dumps(example, indent=2)
Out[7]: '{\n  "a\\tb": "\\nthis\\tis\\nsome\\ttext\\n"\n}'

In [8]: print(json.dumps(example, indent=2))
{
  "a\tb": "\nthis\tis\nsome\ttext\n"
}
```

The behaviour I want (and expect) is this:

```
> print(d)
{'a    b': '
this    is
some    text
'}

> pprint.pprint(d)
{
  'a    b': '
this    is
some    text
'
}
```

or maybe, if pprint were really smart:

```
> pprint.pprint(d)
{
  'a    b': '
  this    is
  some    text
  '
}
```

...but I can't seem to built-in way to do this!

I'd like to know what the standard/best way to do this is, and if there isn't one, why not? Is there a special reason that `repr()` is always called on strings instead of `str()` when printing dicts (and other containers)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prettyprint a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file)

Comment: @Schalton nope, different question.

Comment: Yeah -- I noticed afterwards

Answer (score 1):

more general answer:

```
def myPrint(txt)
    print(bytes(str(txt), 'utf-8').decode("unicode_escape"))

myPrint(example)

{'a b': '
this    is
some    text
'}
```

---

Playing with this a bit more:

**NOTE** It's generally a bad idea to overwrite built-ins, and this might cause other problems, but.......

```
import builtins

def print(*args, literal = False):
        if literal:
            builtins.print(bytes(str(" ".join([str(ag) for ag in args])), 'utf-8').decode("unicode_escape"))
        else:
            builtins.print(*args)
```

---

```
print(example, literal = True)
{'a b': '
this    is
some    text
'}

print(example)
{'a\tb': '\nthis\tis\nsome\ttext\n'}

print(example, literal = False)
{'a\tb': '\nthis\tis\nsome\ttext\n'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this more generic but it'l work for `\n` and `\t` as is

```
example = {'a\tb': '\nthis\tis\nsome\ttext\n'}

def myPrint(txt):
    txt = str(txt)
    swaps = [("\\n", "\n"),
             ("\\t", "\t")]
    for swap in swaps:
        txt= txt.replace(swap[0], swap[1])
    print(txt)

myPrint(example)

{'a b': '
this    is
some    text
'}
```

Comment: your desired output starts with a \n which you could hard code in, it was unclear if you forgot it in your example variable or if you wanted it built in -- easy enough to check if \n is in the beginning and end of the string and add it if it isnt

Comment: a more succinct version of what you wrote might be: `print(str(example).replace('\\n', '\n').replace('\\t', '\t'))`

Comment: @Timir I think that's only for Python 2

Comment: Timir, that 'works' just had to convert the string to bytes first, see my second answer