# Python List to Nested Json

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

I am having the following problem.

```
class Inventory:
    def __init__(self,project_no,country,category,product,count):
        self.project_no = project_no
        self.country = country
        self.category = category
        self.product = product
        self.count = count
inventory_list = []
inventory_list.append(Inventory(1,'USA','Beverages','Milk',2))
inventory_list.append(Inventory(1,'USA','Beverages','Juice',5))
inventory_list.append(Inventory(1,'USA','Snacks','Potato Chips',2))
inventory_list.append(Inventory(1,'USA','Oils','Canola',5))
inventory_list.append(Inventory(1,'USA','Oils','Olive',8))
inventory_list.append(Inventory(1,'CAN','Beverages','Milk',7))
inventory_list.append(Inventory(1,'CAN','Beverages','Juice',8))
inventory_list.append(Inventory(1,'CAN','Snacks','Potato Chips',8))
inventory_list.append(Inventory(1,'CAN','Oils','Canola',3))
inventory_list.append(Inventory(1,'CAN','Oils','Olive',4))

{'Inventory': [{'Country': inv.country , 'Category' : [{inv.category : [{'Product' : inv.product}]}] }  for inv in inventory_list]}
```

This code is giving me the following output.

> ```
> {'Inventory': [{'Country': 'USA',
>    'Category': [{'Beverages': [{'Product': 'Milk'}]}]},
>   {'Country': 'USA', 'Category': [{'Beverages': [{'Product': 'Juice'}]}]},
>   {'Country': 'USA', 'Category': [{'Snacks': [{'Product': 'Potato Chips'}]}]},
>   {'Country': 'USA', 'Category': [{'Oils': [{'Product': 'Canola'}]}]},
>   {'Country': 'USA', 'Category': [{'Oils': [{'Product': 'Olive'}]}]},
>   {'Country': 'CAN', 'Category': [{'Beverages': [{'Product': 'Milk'}]}]},
>   {'Country': 'CAN', 'Category': [{'Beverages': [{'Product': 'Juice'}]}]},
>   {'Country': 'CAN', 'Category': [{'Snacks': [{'Product': 'Potato Chips'}]}]},
>   {'Country': 'CAN', 'Category': [{'Oils': [{'Product': 'Canola'}]}]},
>   {'Country': 'CAN', 'Category': [{'Oils': [{'Product': 'Olive'}]}]}]}
> ```

What I actually need is more like below.

> ```
> {
>   "Inventory": [{
>           "country": "USA",
>           "category": [{
>               "Beverages": [{
>                   "product": "Milk",
>                   "count": 2
>               }, {
>                   "product": "Juice",
>                   "count": 5
>               }]
>           }, {
>               "Snacks": [{
>                   "product": "Potato Chips",
>                   "count": 2
>               }]
>           }, {
>               "Oils": [{
>                   "product": "Canola",
>                   "count": 5
>               }, {
>                   "product": "Olive",
>                   "count": 8
>               }]
>           }]
>
>       }, {
>           "country": "CAN",
>           "category": [{
>               "Beverages": [{
>                   "product": "Milk",
>                   "count": 7
>               }, {
>                   "product": "Juice",
>                   "count": 8
>               }]
>           }, {
>               "Snacks": [{
>                   "product": "Potato Chips",
>                   "count": 8
>               }]
>           }, {
>               "Oils": [{
>                   "product": "Canola",
>                   "count": 3
>               }, {
>                   "product": "Olive",
>                   "count": 4
>               }]
>           }]
>       }
>
>   ]
> }
> ```

How to do this?
I thought list comprehension is the way to go.
But I am having trouble beyond this point.
I thought this should be really easy for a python coder.
With my limited python I could only reach this far.
If anyone can help.

Comment: How is that code giving that output? The code doesn't output anything. Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
for more asking related details.

Comment: @CristiFati The code certainly does output something, at least in an IPython console.

Comment: @CristiFati I am using Jupyter Notebook. I get output.

Comment: If you convert your `dict` to a JSON string, and you can use the the built-in `json` package for pretty printing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file https://appdividend.com/2019/04/15/how-to-convert-python-dictionary-to-json-tutorial-with-example/

Comment: @mypetlion Sorry the problem I am facing is not with the prettiness of the output but the actual structure itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you try serializing your **Inventory** class using the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.  However, it looks like you'll want to reorganize your data a bit.  From what I can tell, you want to have an **inventory** that has a collection of **countries** which contain a set of **products** separated into **categories**.

First, let's define the **Product** class:

```
class Product(object):
    def __init__(self, name, count):
        self.product = name
        self.count = count
```

Next, we can define the **Country** class as a container for a set **Products**, arranged in a dictionary using the **category** name as the key.

```
class Country(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.categories = dict()

    def add_product_to_category(self, category, product):
        if category not in self.categories:
            self.categories[category] = []
        self.categories[category].append(product)
```

Then, we can re-define the **Inventory** class as a container for a set of **Country** objects.

```
class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self, project_no):
        self.project_no = project_no
        self.countries = []
```

Next, we can use simple methods to fill out our classes with the required data.

```
inv = Inventory(1)

us_set = Country('USA')
us_set.add_product_to_category('Beverages', Product('Milk', 2))
us_set.add_product_to_category('Beverages', Product('Juice', 5))
us_set.add_product_to_category('Snacks', Product('Potato Chips', 2))
us_set.add_product_to_category('Oils', Product('Canola', 5))
us_set.add_product_to_category('Oils', Product('Olive', 8))

canada_set = Country('CAN')
canada_set.add_product_to_category('Beverages', Product('Milk', 7))
canada_set.add_product_to_category('Beverages', Product('Juice', 8))
canada_set.add_product_to_category('Snacks', Product('Potato Chips', 8))
canada_set.add_product_to_category('Oils', Product('Canola', 3))
canada_set.add_product_to_category('Oils', Product('Olive', 4))

inv.countries.append(us_set)
inv.countries.append(canada_set)
```

Finally, (to actually answer your question, lul) to serialize the **Inventory** class, we have to define an encoder to use:

```
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o.__dict__
```

Now, we can just call json.dumps() to get a string output of our serialized **Inventory**.

```
json.dumps(inv, indent=2, cls=MyEncoder)
```

The output isn't *exactly* what you laid out, but I think this method will work well for you.

```
{
  "project_no": 1, 
  "countries": [
    {
      "name": "USA", 
      "categories": {
        "Beverages": [
          {
            "count": 2, 
            "product": "Milk"
          }, 
          {
            "count": 5, 
            "product": "Juice"
          }
        ], 
        "Oils": [
          {
            "count": 5, 
            "product": "Canola"
          }, 
          {
            "count": 8, 
            "product": "Olive"
          }
        ], 
        "Snacks": [
          {
            "count": 2, 
            "product": "Potato Chips"
          }
        ]
      }
    }, 
    {
      "name": "CAN", 
      "categories": {
        "Beverages": [
          {
            "count": 7, 
            "product": "Milk"
          }, 
          {
            "count": 8, 
            "product": "Juice"
          }
        ], 
        "Oils": [
          {
            "count": 3, 
            "product": "Canola"
          }, 
          {
            "count": 4, 
            "product": "Olive"
          }
        ], 
        "Snacks": [
          {
            "count": 8, 
            "product": "Potato Chips"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the `json` module, e.g.

```
import json
...
inv_json = {'Inventory': [{'Country': inv.country , 'Category' : [{inv.category : [{'Product' : inv.product}]}] }  for inv in inventory_list]}
json_formatted_str = json.dumps(x, indent=2)
print(json_formatted_str)
```

https://www.journaldev.com/33302/python-pretty-print-json

Comment: The problem is not prettyfying the json. It is the content of the json itself that need some work.

Comment: what's the content you want fixed? what are you expecting to see that you're not?

Comment: For example the 'Country': 'USA' is repeated in my output. But in the desired output it is only occurring once.

Comment: ah i see. I think james-trickington's answer will suffice in that case