# how to pretty print a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, pretty-print

I have the following list:

```py
import json
import pprint

scoring_dictionary=[{'IMEI': '867',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24',
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Probability': 0.12},
 {'IMEI': '430',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24',
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Probability': 0.12},
 {'IMEI': '658',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24',
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Probability': 0.12},
 {'IMEI': '157',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24',
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Probability': 0.12},
 {'IMEI': '521',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24',
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Probability': 0.12}]
```

And I want to pretty print this in the standard output of a cell.
Having seen this code on an online similar question,

```py
print("The list of dictionaries per scored asset id: {0}".format(json.dumps(json.loads(scoring_dictionary), indent=4)))
```

But the output still remains bad

```py
"The list of dictionaries per scored asset id: [{'IMEI': '867', 'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24', 'RAG': 'G', 'Probability': 0.12}, {'IMEI': '430', 'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24', 'RAG': 'G', 'Probability': 0.12}...]" # a straight text of string without intends
```

Apart from the list of dictionaries I want also to pretty print a dictionary which seems like:

```py
{'failed_devices': ['334', '897', '485'], 'partially_succeeded_devices': ['867', '430', '658', '157', '521'], 'total_failures': 705, 'total_partially_succeeded': 268, 'total_succeeded': 26, 'total': 999, 'timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24', 'failures_threshold': 0.1, 'failed_percentage_out_of_total': 0.7057057057057057}
```

I want to pretty print it in the same exact way like the above list of dictionaries.

[UPDATE]
This worked better than pprint. Thanks to all answers. Appreciate your concern.

```py
print("The list of sotred metrics depicting the complete batch scoring execution: {0}".format(json.dumps(scoring_dictionary, indent=2)))
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file

Comment: @CoryKramer This was the one post I saw but I have the exact same output. I will retry it but I don't think something will change

Comment: that's not the output of json.dumps, as JSON must use double quotes, not single quotes.  the code you have shown for print() does not match the output you have shown.  You also don't have "{}" which is necessary for format to insert the string

Comment: Try [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html).  In this case `from pprint import  print; print(lst)`, where lst is the list.

Comment: `[{'IMEI': '867',` is not valid JSON.  Your code does not match the output.

Comment: @user120242 Should I use " " double code instead? Because Python does not give me an error on that

Comment: @NikSp what I'm saying is that the string you have is coming from somewhere else some other code, not the json.dumps you have there.  That code would not produce a string with single quotes in it.  it's more likely you have a print("The list...") followed later by print(devices_succeed_failed)

Comment: @user120242 please check my update :)

Comment: @CoryKramer I rechecked the posr and you were right json.dumps works fine

Answer (score 2):

For prettier prints you can check out [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html):

```
import pprint 
pprint.pprint(data)


pprint.pprint(data)

[{'IMEI': '867',
  'Probability': 0.12,
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24'},
 {'IMEI': '430',
  'Probability': 0.12,
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24'},
 {'IMEI': '658',
  'Probability': 0.12,
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24'},
 {'IMEI': '157',
  'Probability': 0.12,
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24'},
 {'IMEI': '521',
  'Probability': 0.12,
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file)

```py
#list of dictionaries
scoring_dictionary=[{'IMEI': '358639059721867',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24',
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Probability': 0.12},
 {'IMEI': '358639059721430',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24',
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Probability': 0.12},
 {'IMEI': '358639059721658',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24',
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Probability': 0.12},
 {'IMEI': '358639059721157',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24',
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Probability': 0.12},
 {'IMEI': '358639059721521',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24',
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Probability': 0.12},
 {'IMEI': '358639059721713',
  'Timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24',
  'RAG': 'G',
  'Probability': 0.12}]

#dictionary
devices_succeed_failed={'failed_devices': ['334', '897', '485'], 'partially_succeeded_devices': ['867', '430', '658', '157', '521'], 'total_failures': 705, 'total_partially_succeeded': 268, 'total_succeeded': 26, 'total': 999, 'timestamp': '2020-07-02 13-29-24', 'failures_threshold': 0.1, 'failed_percentage_out_of_total': 0.7057057057057057}
```

```py
# WORKED FOR BOTH CASES
print("The list of sotred metrics depicting the complete batch scoring execution: {0}".format(json.dumps(scoring_dictionary, indent=2)))

print("The list of sotred metrics depicting the complete batch scoring execution: {0}".format(json.dumps(devices_succeed_failed, indent=2)))
```