# Beautifying JSON output in terminal - Visual Studio Code - Python

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I would like to make the output of JSON string prettier in the terminal of VSC.

I'm currently using python 3.8.5 32 bit in a venv, and the latest version of VSC. I've got the python and python extension pack installed. I tried Prettify JSON but that doesn't seem to do anything.

So far I've tried using:

`print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))`

However this just produces a large string that is difficult to read [Image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRTeh.png)

I'm a relative beginner with Python and just started with VSC in the last couple of days.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prettyprint a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```