# How to pretty print json String whose value is also a json String in python

Tags: python, json, pretty-print

I am using python's json module to pretty print a json String which looks like below

```
"{"content" : "{"key" : "value"}","otherContent: "{"key2":"value"}"}"
```

i want it to look like so when i print it

```
{ 
 c1: {
       key: value
     },
 c2: {
        key2: value
     }
}
```

or something similar to this format, how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Is this the maximum depth (i.e. can the inner JSON string have within it another JSON string)?

Comment: turn that json into dict, then pprint(dict) - reference: look at pprint https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prettyprint a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file)

Comment: What do you mean by "a json string"? Once you have a string, it's a string, and it doesn't matter whether you got it by loading a json document or any other way.

Comment: urn that json into dict, then pprint(dict) ! this worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to reformat your json a bit by adding some square brackets, but this works:

```
json_string = '{"content": [{"key": "value"}], "otherContent": [{"key2": "value"}]}'

loaded_json = json.loads( json_string )

print(json.dumps(loaded_json , sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "key": "value"
        }
    ],
    "otherContent": [
        {
            "key2": "value"
        }
    ]
}
```