# Outputting a pretty json file with Python (json keys and values surrounded by double quotes)

Tags: python

Got an array with objects called `data` that looks something like this:

```
[
   {
       'type': 'motorcycle', 
       'properties': [ 
           {
               'type': 'large', 
               'brand': 'kawasaki', 
               'attribute': {
                    'id': '98-fda7d7fa', 
                    'title': 'Ninja'
                },
            }
         ]
    }
[
```

I can output a json file like this:

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    print(data, file=f)
```

but it comes out with single quotes and not double quotes,

so I can't really automatically format it on my code editor

I am trying to follow the [top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file) to fix that:

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    print(json.load(data), file=f)
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html, you can just directly dump the list.

Comment: that works! feel free to add it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

[`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) reads JSON already stored in a file, and converts it into a Python object. You want [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump):

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```