# Print a json following a specific pattern

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a file `.csv` like that:

```
ID;Name;Sports
1;Mark;["Football", "Volleyball"]
2;Luuk;["Fencing"]
3;Carl;["Swimming", "Basketball"]
```

My goal is to print on a file `.json` the following:

```
[
{
"ID": 1,
"Name": "Mark",
"Sports": ["Football", "Volleyball"]
}
,
{
"ID": 2,
"Name": "Luuk",
"Sports": ["Fencing"]
}
,
{
"ID": 3,
"Name": "Carl",
"Sports": ["Swimming", "Basketball"]
}
]
```

My code to produce the list:

```
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=";", converters={'Sports': literal_eval})

columns = list(df.columns)

json = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    line = {}
    for j in range(len(columns)):
        line[columns[j]] = df.iloc[i, j]
    json.append(line)
```

How can I smartly print my list in the same format written above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=";", converters={'Sports': literal_eval})


json = df.to_json(orient='records')
print (json)
[{"ID":1,"Name":"Mark","Sports":["Football","Volleyball"]},
 {"ID":2,"Name":"Luuk","Sports":["Fencing"]},
 {"ID":3,"Name":"Carl","Sports":["Swimming","Basketball"]}]
```

EDIT: If need create `json` file use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=";", converters={'Sports': literal_eval})

d = df.to_dict(orient='records')
print (d)
[{"ID":1,"Name":"Mark","Sports":["Football","Volleyball"]},
 {"ID":2,"Name":"Luuk","Sports":["Fencing"]},
 {"ID":3,"Name":"Carl","Sports":["Swimming","Basketball"]}]

import json
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(d, fp)
```

Comment: My question however was about how to print on a file `.json` in the way I reported in the question

Comment: @LJG - Answer was edited.

Comment: It gives me an error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dump'

Comment: @LJG - For me working perfectly, is possible upgrade python?

Comment: Now it works. There was a variable called `json` in the previous part of the code. Do you know a way to print the list with the same formatting I used in the question? That is, to go to head every time it is required.

Comment: @LJG - maybe help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

data = {"data" : []}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    data.append(row.to_dict())

with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

Comment: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'