# how do I append something to a list after an element not at the end of the list

Tags: python, json

I have a list...

```
   delimiterList = ["[", "]", "{", "}", ","]

def getData():
    Input = input("Enter JSON")
    return Input

def saveInputAsList(input):
    inputList = []
    for i in input:
        inputList.append(i)
    return inputList

def Format():
    input = saveInputAsList(getData())
    if delimiterList in input:
        input.append('\n')
        return input
        
 

print(Format())
```

1. ask user for input, save to list I want to loop through the list
2. If any strings in my delimiterlist in user input append '\n' to list
3. the output should be ['a', '"', '\n', 'b', '[', '\n']

I'm trying to work on a JSON beautifier without using libraries

Comment: For printing JSON you can use json.dumps, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944035/8271728

Comment: @SteveMapes I know this, I have used it before. I'm trying to write my own formatter without libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use insert method on a list. See python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

This method will help you to insert an element at a given index. If you are looking to the first occurence of an element in a list, you can use `index` method.

So:

```py
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
my_list.insert(my_list.index('b') + 1, 'z')
print(my_list)
```

will output

```
['a', 'b', 'z', 'c']
```