# Trying to get each search result to show up in a newline instead having it all cluttered up

Tags: python, json, pretty-print

How do I get each search result to go from top to bottom instead of all cluttered up left to right?

picture of how it is right now:

[image]

how I want it to be:
[image]

code:

```
from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch

videosSearch = VideosSearch('wonderwall', limit=100)
print(videosSearch.result())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prettyprint a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty Print is the tool you seek.

```
    from pprint import pprint
    from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch
    videosSearch = VideosSearch('wonderwall', limit=100) 
    pprint(videoSearch.result())
```

May need to cast result to JSON. Let me look up the YouTube API.