# How to generate a json file with a nested dictionary from pandas df?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, pivot

I need to generate a json file with a specific format from a pandas dataframe. The dataframe looks like this:

| user_id | product_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 01-01-2022 |
| 1 | 24 | 05-01-2022 |
| 2 | 56 | 05-06-2022 |
| 3 | 23 | 02-07-2022 |
| 3 | 24 | 01-02-2022 |
| 3 | 56 | 02-01-2022 |

And the json file needs to have the following format:

```
{
  "user_id": 1,
  "items": [{
        "product_id": 23,
        "date": 01-01-2022
        }, {
        "product_id": 24,
        "date": 05-01-2022
        }]
}
{
 "userid": 2,
 "items": [{
        "product_id": 56,
        "date": 05-06-2022
        }]
}
...etc
```

I've tried the following, but it's not the right format:

```
result = (now.groupby('user_id')['product_id','date'].apply(lambda x: dict(x.values)).to_json())
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
out = (df[['product_id','date']].apply(dict, axis=1)
       .groupby(df['user_id']).apply(list)
       .to_frame('items').reset_index()
       .to_dict('records'))
```

```
print(out)

[{'user_id': 1, 'items': [{'product_id': 23, 'date': '01-01-2022'}, {'product_id': 24, 'date': '05-01-2022'}]},
{'user_id': 2, 'items': [{'product_id': 56, 'date': '05-06-2022'}]}, 
{'user_id': 3, 'items': [{'product_id': 23, 'date': '02-07-2022'}, {'product_id': 24, 'date': '01-02-2022'}, {'product_id': 56, 'date': '02-01-2022'}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code can solve the issue. It first converts the datetime to string for the date column. Then, it converts the dataframe into the desired format.

*data* is your data table saved as the excel file.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import json

# Read the excel data
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet_name=0)

# Change the data type of the date column (day-month-year)
data['date'] = data['date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))

# Convert to desired json format
json_data = (data.groupby(['user_id'])
               .apply(lambda x: x[['product_id','date']].to_dict('records'))
               .reset_index()
               .rename(columns={0:'items'})
               .to_json(orient='records'))

# Pretty print the result
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944035/10905535
json_data = json.loads(json_data)
print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4, sort_keys=False))
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "product_id": 23,
                "date": "01-01-2022"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 24,
                "date": "05-01-2022"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user_id": 2,
        "items": [
            {
                "product_id": 56,
                "date": "05-06-2022"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user_id": 3,
        "items": [
            {
                "product_id": 23,
                "date": "02-07-2022"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 24,
                "date": "01-02-2022"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 56,
                "date": "02-01-2022"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```