# How to format a dictionary with a list of items in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-re

I have a python dictionary that I want to look like this:

```
{"name": "BOB", 
    "item1": {
        "item name": "bread",
        "quantity of item ": 10,
        "price of item": "3.00"
    }, 
    "item2": {
        "item name": "milk",
        "quantity of item ": 15,
        "price of item": "9.00"
    }
}
```

currently it looks like this

```
{"name": "BOB", "item1": {"item name": "bread", "quantity of item ": 10, "price of item": "3.00"}, "item2": {"item name": "milk", "quantity of item ": 15, "price of item": "9.00"}}
```

The list of items can be different and does not have a fixed amount of items, so I would also need to to know how to do that

I have tried to add new lines in the dictionaries but it would not work and it would just put '\n' in to my dictionary

Comment: _I have a python dictionary that I want to look like this_ In what context?  Printed on the screen?  Written to a file?

Comment: use [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

Comment: Inside of a JSON file would be my preferred form of output.

Comment: If it's in a json file, why do you care what it looks like?

Comment: I am looking to write the dictionary to a JSON so I would just json.dump to add the formatted dictionary

Comment: `pprint` for printing to the console, `pprint.pformat` for building a string representation of the pretty-printed version, `json.dumps` with the `indent` param for JSON.

Comment: JSON example: [How to prettyprint a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file)

Comment: I am making sure the information is readable.

Comment: pprint does indeed work thank you all for the tips.

Comment: The output from `pprint` is quite readable, but it does not exactly match your format.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to `json.dump()` it into a JSON file, using the `json.dump()` function you could pass in the `indent` argument for indentation (appears to be what you want) You can read more about it [here](https://pynative.com/python-prettyprint-json-data/)
An example:

```py
json.dump(jsonData, jsonFile, indent=2) # indentation is usually in spaces, so 2 would mean 2 spaces indentation, but you can replace it with '\t' for tabs
```

All this does is add indentation to the file to make it easier to read