# Need help converting dataframe to json format

Tags: python, json

I have a table which has some sample data as provided below

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "mode": ["single_table_list", "single_table_list", "single_table_list", "relational_table_list", "relational_table_list"],
  "type": ["type_a", "type_b", "type_c", "parent_table", "child_table"],
  "file_name": ["file_a", "file_b", "file_c", "file_d", "file_e"],
  "file_path": ["path_a", "path_b", "path_c", "path_d", "path_e"],
  "file_sample": ["sample_a", "sample_b", "sample_c", "sample_d", "sample_e"],
  "target_file_name": ["tgt_name_a", "tgt_name_b", "tgt_name_c", "tgt_name_d", "tgt_name_e"],
  "target_file_path": ["tgt_path_a", "tgt_path_b", "tgt_path_c", "tgt_path_d", "tgt_path_e"],
  "child_table": ["","","","child_d",""],
  "parent_key": ["","","","key_d",""],
  "parent_table": ["","","","","parent_e"],
  "child_key": ["","","","","key_e"]
}
```

I am facing difficulty with the output into the required formatting, how do I go about implementing this so that it provides the output as shown below.
Is it possible to have the JSON output structured as such?

```
{
  "single_table_list": {
    "1":{
    "type": "type_a",
    "file_name": "file_a",
    "file_path": "path_a",
    "file_sample": "sample_a",
    "target_file_name": "tgt_name_a",
    "target_file_path": "tgt_path_a"
    },
    "2":{
    "type": "type_b",
    "file_name": "file_b",
    "file_path": "path_b",
    "file_sample": "sample_b",
    "target_file_name": "tgt_name_b",
    "target_file_path": "tgt_path_b"
    },
    "3":{
    "type": "type_c",
    "file_name": "file_c",
    "file_path": "path_c",
    "file_sample": "sample_c",
    "target_file_name": "tgt_name_c",
    "target_file_path": "tgt_path_c"
    }
  },
  "relational_table_list": {
    "1":{
      "parent_table_list":{
        "type": "type_parent",
        "file_name": "file_d",
        "file_path": "path_d",
        "file_sample": "sample_d",
        "target_file_name": "tgt_name_d",
        "target_file_path": "tgt_path_d",
        "child_table": "child_d"
        "parent_key": "key_d"
        },
      "child_table_list":{
        "type": "type_child",
        "file_name": "file_e",
        "file_path": "path_e",
        "file_sample": "sample_e",
        "target_file_name": "tgt_name_e",
        "target_file_path": "tgt_path_e",
        "parent_table": "parent_e",
        "child_key": "key_e"
        }
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: It [is not possible to "help you"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/) here as this is **not a discussion forum**. We require a **clear, specific, direct** question about **one specific step** in a task. It is your responsibility before asking to try to break the problem down into logical steps first, and figure out where you are actually stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prettyprint a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file)

Comment: _"Is it possible to have the JSON output structured as such?"_ Yes, it is possible. There is no simple function for that, you have to code it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "json" module
json.dumps is uesd to convert python Object to JSON String.And you should give argument"indent". there is a example

```
import json

data = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 30,
    "address": {
        "city": "Beijing",
        "country": "China",
    },
}

json_string = json.dumps(data, indent=2)

print(json_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure what you want
but I think you want to organizes the data according to the desired structure, and then converts it to a JSON string with proper indentation. The output should match your specified JSON structure.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = {
    "mode": ["single_table_list", "single_table_list", "single_table_list", "relational_table_list", "relational_table_list"],
    "type": ["type_a", "type_b", "type_c", "parent_table", "child_table"],
    "file_name": ["file_a", "file_b", "file_c", "file_d", "file_e"],
    "file_path": ["path_a", "path_b", "path_c", "path_d", "path_e"],
    "file_sample": ["sample_a", "sample_b", "sample_c", "sample_d", "sample_e"],
    "target_file_name": ["tgt_name_a", "tgt_name_b", "tgt_name_c", "tgt_name_d", "tgt_name_e"],
    "target_file_path": ["tgt_path_a", "tgt_path_b", "tgt_path_c", "tgt_path_d", "tgt_path_e"],
    "child_table": ["", "", "", "child_d", ""],
    "parent_key": ["", "", "", "key_d", ""],
    "parent_table": ["", "", "", "", "parent_e"],
    "child_key": ["", "", "", "", "key_e"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Initialize an empty dictionary to store the result
result_dict = {}

# Iterate through the DataFrame rows
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    mode = row["mode"]
    row_dict = {
        "type": row["type"],
        "file_name": row["file_name"],
        "file_path": row["file_path"],
        "file_sample": row["file_sample"],
        "target_file_name": row["target_file_name"],
        "target_file_path": row["target_file_path"]
    }

    if mode not in result_dict:
        result_dict[mode] = {}

    if mode == "relational_table_list":
        row_dict["parent_table_list"] = {
            "type": "type_parent",
            "file_name": row["file_name"],
            "file_path": row["file_path"],
            "file_sample": row["file_sample"],
            "target_file_name": row["target_file_name"],
            "target_file_path": row["target_file_path"],
            "child_table": row["child_table"],
            "parent_key": row["parent_key"]
        }

        row_dict["child_table_list"] = {
            "type": "type_child",
            "file_name": row["file_name"],
            "file_path": row["file_path"],
            "file_sample": row["file_sample"],
            "target_file_name": row["target_file_name"],
            "target_file_path": row["target_file_path"],
            "parent_table": row["parent_table"],
            "child_key": row["child_key"]
        }

    result_dict[mode][str(index + 1)] = row_dict

# Convert the result dictionary to JSON
result_json = json.dumps(result_dict, indent=2)
print(result_json)
```