# formating my json output file using python

Tags: python, separator

```
with open(output_file_path_final, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(final, f, separators=(',', ':'))
```

this is the key lines of my python code and I get output as below,

```
{"frame.number":[80.0,87.0,93.0,95.0,99.0,....],"frame.timestamp [s]":[1324055659.394, 1324055659.488, 1324055659.607, 1324055659.613, 1324055659.695,.....], ......... "{31} EVSE Maximum Power Limit [W]":[null, null, null, null, null, null,....]}
```

`separators=(',\n', ':'))` : this solution didn't work because it gives every parameter in new line.

```
{"frame.number":[80.0, 87.0, 93.0, 95.0, 99.0, 103.0, 106.0,.......],
  "frame.timestamp [s]":[1324055659.394, 1324055659.488, 1324055659.607, 1324055659.613, 1324055659.695,.....],
.
.
.
.
  "{31} EVSE Maximum Power Limit [W]":[null, null, null, null, null, null,....]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prettyprint a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you check [the docs for `json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump), you can read:

> If indent is a non-negative integer or string, then JSON array elements and object members will be pretty-printed with that indent level. An indent level of 0, negative, or "" will only insert newlines

so consider `json.dump(final, f, indent=4)` instead

Comment: I have already used it and for your appriciation I have used it again and I got result like below,
"frame.number":[
        80.0,
        87.0,
        93.0,
        95.0,
        99.0,
        103.0,
        106.0,
        109.0,
        112.0,
        114.0,
        119.0,
        121.0,

this is vertically means all value shift into new line.
That's I definitely do not want I just want to shift paramere into new line.

Comment: Try `indent=0` then, that should just put every key on a new line without indenting

Comment: If I am not using indent then it automatically act as a 0 so the result is nothing to change.

Comment: Read the docs again; there's a serious difference between numerical `0` and the default singleton value `None`. As it states in my answer, numerical `0` **will only insert newlines**. Whereas `None` (the default value) makes it insert **no newlines**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I tried your solution but it ws not work.
That's why I gave you negative feedback.