# Update a JSON file with Python and keep the original format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a Python script that updates some value of a JSON file, and the original format of my JSON looks like:

[image]

To edit the value I use this code:

```
 import json

 status_wifi  = "ok" 

 with open("config_wifi.json", "r") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    data['wifi_session']['status'] = status_wifi 

 with open("config_wifi.json", "w") as jsonFile:
  json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

But when the values are updated, the format of my JSON is compressed like this:

[image]

I want the JSON file to keep its original format with all spaces and line breaks. How could I do that?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty-Print JSON Data to a File using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170288/pretty-print-json-data-to-a-file-using-python)

Comment: Thanks @jorcharpe ! yes perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `json.dumps(json_obj, indent=4)`

Example:

```
import json

status_wifi  = "ok" 

with open("config_wifi.json", "r") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    data['wifi_session']['status'] = status_wifi 

with open("config_wifi.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(json.dumps(data, indent=4), jsonFile)
```

The indent is the number of spaces for a tab.
If you set this parameter, the JSON will be formatted.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: Please add some context as to why this works. Especially since dropping that line of code in won't work.

Comment: I guess it's better now.