# json.dump to a gzip file in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a object to a gzipped json file in one step (minimising code, and possibly saving memory space). My initial idea (python3) was thus:

```
import gzip, json
with gzip.open("/tmp/test.gz", mode="wb") as f:
  json.dump({"a": 1}, f)
```

This however fails: `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`, which I think has to do with a string not being encoded to bytes. So what is the proper way to do this?

*Current solution that I'm unhappy with:*

Opening the file in text-mode solves the problem:

```
import gzip, json
with gzip.open("/tmp/test.gz", mode="wt") as f:
  json.dump({"a": 1}, f)
```

however I don't like text-mode. In my mind (and maybe this is wrong, but supported by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257869/difference-between-binary-and-text-i-o-in-python-on-windows)), text mode is used to fix line-endings. This shouldn't be an issue because json doesn't have line endings, but I don't like it (possibly) messing with my bytes, it (possibly) is slower because it's looking for line-endings to fix, and (worst of all) I don't understand why something about line-endings fixes my encoding problems?

Comment: Actually I just realised that the gzip-part has nothing to do with this all, I should rewrite the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**offtopic**: I should have dived into the docs a bit further than I initially did.

The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) show:

> Normally, files are opened in *text mode*, that means, you read and write strings from and to the file, which are encoded in a specific encoding (the default being UTF-8). 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in *binary mode*: now the data is read and written in the form of bytes objects. This mode should be used for all files that don’t contain text.

I don't fully agree that the result from a json encode is a string (I think it should be a set of bytes, since it explicitly defines that it uses utf-8 encoding), but I noticed this before. So I guess text mode it is.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/49535758/1335793 quotes the docs "The json module always produces `str` objects, not `bytes` objects."  I think this answer explains it well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450065/python-3-read-write-compressed-json-objects-from-to-gzip-file?noredirect=1&lq=1 json.dump is really doing 2 things, serializing your dict object to a string, then writing it to a file with an encoding (similar to file.write() )

Comment: JSON module is either serializing from an object to a string/file (dumps/dump) or deserializing to an object from a string/file (loads/load), and JSON is a textual representation of data, intended to be stored or transmitted as text, so it does make sense.