# Is there a way to use `json.dump` with `gzip`?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, gzip

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450065/python-3-read-write-compressed-json-objects-from-to-gzip-file) is a great answer about how to use `json.dumps` to write to a gzip file. What I would like to do is to use the `dump` method instead to serialize the json directly into a `GzipFile` object.

Example code:

```
import gzip, json

data = # a dictionary of data here
with gzip.open(write_file, 'w') as zipfile:
   json.dump(data, zipfile)
```

The error raised is

```
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like objet is required, not 'str'
```

I believe this is caused because the gzip write() method wants a bytes object passed to it. Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#basic-usage),

> The json module always produces str objects, not bytes objects.
>   Therefore, fp.write() must support str input.

Is there a way to wrap the `json` string output as bytes so that `GzipFile`'s `write()` will handle it? Or is the only way to do this to use `json.dumps` and `encode()` the resulting string into a bytes object, as in the other linked answer?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The gzip module supports it out of the box: just declare an encoding and it will encode the unicode string to bytes before writing it to the file:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open(write_file, 'wt', encoding="ascii") as zipfile:
       json.dump(data, zipfile)
```

Make sure you specify using text mode (`'wt'`).

As json has encoded any non ascii character, ascii encoding is enough, but you could use any other encoding compatible with ascii for the first 128 code points like Latin1, UTF-8, etc

Comment: Under what circumstances is the `encoding` kwarg actually necessary? Was enough for me to ensure text mode, i.e. `'w'` to `'wt'`.

Answer (score 0):

to convert a string to a bytes array you can do something like this

```
json.dump(bytes(data,"utf-8"), zipfile)
```

Comment: That only works for a string. I clarified the question that I am dealing with a `dict`, but I'd like a general solution for anything that can be put into `json`.