# Python how to write in binary mode a list of hexadecimals?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, hex, newline

I have a string of hex representations of text that I need to write to a file.

```py
toWrite = "020203480A"

with open("example.bin", "w") as file:
   file.write(chr(int(toWrite, 16)))
```

The problem is that whenever I write LF (0A) Windows automatically adds CR (0D). I know because I open the file in [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) I read `02 02 03 48 0D 0A`.

How do I prevent Windows from adding CR before LF?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you intend to write to the file? Are you trying to write the bytes encoded by the hexadecimal representation in `toWrite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to directly write bytes to a file without [localized line ending behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3257869/11082165), open the file in binary mode instead of text mode:

```
toWrite = "020203480A"

# Note "wb" instead of "w"
with open("example.bin", "wb") as file:
   file.write(bytes.fromhex(toWrite))
```

or, using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.write_bytes) to automatically handle opening and closing the file:

```
from pathlib import Path

toWrite = "020203480A"
p = Path("example.bin")
p.write_bytes(bytes.fromhex(toWrite))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open the file in 'wb' mode, which opens the file in binary mode, preventing Windows from automatically inserting CR before LF.

```
toWrite = "020203480A"

with open("example.bin", "wb") as file:
    file.write(bytes.fromhex(toWrite))
```

Note: bytes.fromhex(toWrite) converts the hex string into a bytes object and writes it to the file as-is.

When you open "example.bin" in HxD, you should see something like this:

```
02 02 03 48 0A
```